# How do I run my If statements through all relevant child elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a risk assessment template for my company, I have if statements that does not want to run through all my child elements. I know i need to create a Function that would concatenate my id with the row number, in order to create a new id. then based on that "id" i should run my if statement. the problem is I am not that experienced to solve the problem.

I am also experiencing difficulties to let the relevant row number reflect next to the row. my solution for the row numbers only append it to the very top of the table.

I have tried everything and even googled a possible solution, however i have had no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Risk Assessment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalise.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Main.css">

</head>

<body id="Mybody">
    <img id="isrm" src="img/isrm.jpg" alt="Isrm Logo">

    <form onsubmit="return false"id="RiskManagement">
        <fieldset >
            <h1>Risk assessment</h1><br>
            <input class="project_details" type="date" placeholder="Date of risk assessment">
            <input class="project_details" type="text" placeholder="Client name">
            <input class="project_details" type="text" placeholder="CEO name">
            <input class="project_details" type="text" placeholder="Project name">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <table class="myTable" id="myTable"> 
                    <th id="nr">#</th>
                    <th>Activity conducted</th>
                    <th>Hazard associated with the activity</th>
                    <th>Risk associated with the hazard</th>
                    <th>Liklihood of risk manifesting</th>
                    <th>Consequence for when risk manifest</th>
                    <th>Risk rating</th>
                    <th>Risk severity level</th>
                    <th>Controls to implement</th>
                 <tr class="MyRow" id="rs">

                     <td><input class="rowNumber" type="number" id="riskNumber" readonly ></td>

                      <td><textarea class="Activity" type="text"></textarea></td> <!--activity input-->

                      <td><textarea class="hazard" type="text"></textarea></td> <!--Hazard input-->

                      <td><textarea class="risk" type="text"></textarea></td> <!--risk input-->

                      <td ><input class="potential" id="Liklihood" type="number" name="risk_liklihood" min="0" max="3"></td> <!--liklihood input-->

                      <td ><input class="Consequence"id="Consequence" type="number" name="risk_consequence" min="0" max="3" ></td> 
                      <!--consequence input-->

                      <td class="riskOnly" id="myRisk"><input  id="Risk_rating" name="Risk_rating" readonly></td> <!--risk rating display-->

                      <td class="severelevel"><input id="Severity_level" type="text" readonly></td> <!--severity level to auto display input-->

                      <td><textarea type="text"></textarea></td>

                      <td>
                        <button class="remove" onclick="removeCurrentRow(0)"><strong>-</strong></button>
                      </td> <!--Remove button-->
              </tr>
            </table>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset class="buttonSpace">
    <button id="addRow" onclick="rowCounting()">+ Add </button>
    <button type="button" id="pdf" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="js/rating.js"></script>
    <script src="js/element_behaviour.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



/*Code to get value from  liklihood input box*/
function getLiklihoodValue(x){
    var x=document.getElementById("Liklihood").value;
    return(x) 
}
getLiklihoodValue();

/*Code to get value from consequence input box*/
function getConsequenceValue(y){
    var y=document.getElementById("Consequence").value;
    return(y)
}
getConsequenceValue();





//code to produce risk rate to the DOM based on liklihood value//
function ProduceRiskRate(){
    var x=getLiklihoodValue();
    var y=getConsequenceValue();

    if(x==1&&y==1){
    return(1);
    } else if (x==2&&y==1){
        return(2);
    }else if(x==3&&y==1){
        return(4);
    }else if(x==1&&y==2){
        return(3);
    }else if(x==2&&y==2){
        return(5);
    }else if(x==3&&y==2){
        return(7);
    }else if(x==1&&y==3){
        return(6);
    }else if(x==2&&y==3){
        return(8);
    }else if(x==3&&y==3){
        return(9);
    }
} 
ProduceRiskRate();


//code to use the risk rate returned by the "Produce risk rate function" and assign it to the risk rating input box.//
function RateRiskRate(z){
           var z = ProduceRiskRate();

    if (z== 1) {
        document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 2) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 3) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 4) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 5) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 6) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 7) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 8) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        } else if (z == 9) {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = ProduceRiskRate();
        }else {
            document.getElementById('Risk_rating').value = 'Not rated';
        }
  }

  document.getElementById("Liklihood").onchange = RateRiskRate;
  document.getElementById("Consequence").onchange = RateRiskRate;
  document.getElementById("Risk_rating").onfocus = RateRiskRate;
  RateRiskRate();





//code to return value in the risk rate section//
function getRiskRate(z) {
    var z = document.getElementById("Risk_rating").value;
    return (z);

  }

//code to rate risk based on condition and display rating in input box//
  function Rate() {
    var z = getRiskRate();

    if (z > 0 && z <= 2) {
        document.getElementById('Severity_level').value = 'Low';
        } else if (z > 2 && z <= 6) {
            document.getElementById('Severity_level').value = 'Medium';
            } else if (z > 6 && z <= 9) {
                document.getElementById('Severity_level').value = 'High';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('Severity_level').value = 'value not defined';
                    }
  }



  document.getElementById("RiskManagement").onchange = Rate;
  /*
  document.getElementById("Risk_rating").onfocus = Rate;
  document.getElementById("Liklihood").onfocus = Rate;
  document.getElementById("Consequence").onfocus = Rate;
  document.getElementById("Risk_rating").onchange = Rate;
*/
Rate();
```

the output I am expecting is for my if statements to run through all relevant sections of my newly added rows, as well as the row numbers to reflect next to each row.

Comment: Is there a formula for risk rate?

Comment: I did that's why I ask. Good code doesn't use that many conditions when it involves numbers. So I assume you have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have comment privileges yet, and I've got to study your question a bit longer to get you an actual answer, but I wanted to let you know a couple of tangential things that might help in the meantime.

Some of your functions (such as getRiskRate) have a parameter and also define a local variable with the same name as that parameter, which most likely means any arguments passed in will never be used. (References to that variable name inside the function will use the local version.)

RateRiskRate has several conditions that all result in the same action (setting the value of the the 'Risk_rating'). This works fine, but you can accomplish the same thing with one if statement by using a double-pipe (||, meaning "or") between your conditions like `if (a == b || c == d)`. And even better, because you're checking the same variable `z` each time, you could actually just say `if ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].includes(z))`.

.  .  .  .  .
Okay, real answer:
Based on your comments, I recommend selecting the likelihood and consequence elements by class instead of id. Then a traditional for loop can pull out your values, like:

```
let allConsequenceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.Consequence');
let allConsequenceValues = [];
for(i = 0; i < allConsequenceElements.length; i++){
  allConsequenceValues.push(parseInt(allConsequenceElements[i].value));
}
// Now we have an array containing all the values from the Consequence column
console.log(allConsequenceValues);
```

And there you have it!

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight, I will keep your advise in mind when doing edits.

Comment: (note: I edited the code sample because my original syntax was wrong)

Comment: More tips I wrote before reading your code thoroughly:

"Running through" HTML requires selecting desired elements. 

If you don't already know, you can get one via methods on its parent element (or any ancestor.) Two common methods are `getElementById` and `querySelectorAll`. 

You pass an argument (like the id or a selector) to the method and get back one or more matching elements like `myElement = document.getElementById("theID");` or `myPseudoArray = querySelectorAll(".my-class")`. (The latter example returns an array-like object containing all the elements with that class.)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the effort in assisting me and providing me with your knowledge. it really helps allot to learn to code properly.

Comment: I finally perused your code and realized I still don't fully understand your question.  After looking at everything for a while, here's what I think you're trying to do:  
Create a function called rowCounting which adds a row (with an automatically generated row number) to the page.  Each column in the new row contains an input element which is assigned an id.  This id is built from two components: the "column id" (representing the kind of input that column takes) and the newly generated row number.  Do I have it?

Comment: Yes but i am more interested in getting my if statements to run through all rows. currently if I add new rows the rating code doesn't want to run due to the- if statements targeting the first row's ID.

Comment: If I can allow my if statements to run through all rows to get the liklihood value and consequence value and then rate the risk based on that input.

Comment: I have changed all getElementById tags to get element by class with the relevant class and used your code. it doesn't seem to work, it returns my if statements as undefined. is there maybe an alternative? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong from here. I tested the code I posted (in Chrome) using your HTML and it returns an array of integers. I'd pay close attention to your browser console for useful error messages (and for logging variable values to see when they stop being what you expect.) And make sure your class names and such don't contain any typos.

Comment: Greatness, I will test this statement again. thanks so much for your effort.

Comment: It works , I am getting my values in an array, is there a possibility where I can compare the first values of each array( consequence array and likelihood array) and then return a value. for instance. consequence array[1,2,3,3] and likelihood array=[3,3,3,3]. if taking the first values consequence=1 and likelihood=3 then the next block should have a value of 2,  and then it should go to the next value in the array and compare and return a value.

Comment: Sure. Assuming your two source arrays are the same length, you make a for loop just like the one in my answer. (Each time through the loop, `i` goes up by 1.) Inside the loop, you do your calculation and push your result to the new array like I did with allConsequenceValues. (The new, empty array must already exist before you start the loop.)
When I say 'do your calculation', I mean your if-else block, where each statement looks generally like `if(a==1 && b==3){ result = 2; }`.
BTW, if you thought my answer was good, please select it as a correct answer (and possibly upvote it.)

Comment: I did up vote your answers, however it seems that I don't have enough points to publicly up vote the answer.  if I understand you correct, i need to create a new array and then use a for loop to get all liklihhood values( as you did) and consequence values(just like your code), then create another for loop to run the length of the new array. only then in block code add my if statements?  can i manipulate the if statement to return the value of each result in a input element in the table?

Comment: Ok, at this point, the easiest way to insert results into the rows would be to add yet another for loop where you select all the target inputs and change their values in order. (This isn't an elegant solution but it's practical at this point.) Assuming you already have an array called `collectedResults` and you want to put its values into the inputs that have the class `severeLevel`, it'd look like `let allSeverityInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".severeLevel"); for( i = 0; i < collectedResults.length; i++) { allSeverityInputs[i].value = collectedResults[i]; }`. I hope that does it.

Comment: it works thanks man i just now need to do my if statement to store results in the array, and then it will all be 100%. I have bought a course at Udemy that explains Arrays. really appreciate the effort .

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad it's to hear it. Are you able to select my answer as "accepted"? A great resource for most everything related to front-end web development is developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web. (Don't miss the top-of-page menu.) If you're doing a whole course on arrays, you'll probably be able to replace your current code with something much more succinct. (One last related thing to be aware of is that functions like querySelector return a list of elements that's very similar to an array but is *not* actually an array, which can be very confusing if you're not ready for it.) Good luck!